# Reactstrap tabs are slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a web application with react. I am using tabs in tabs (nested tabs) and when I click on a tab button it takes a very long time to change.

Every main tab has 8 or 7 sub-tabs and this has to be in this way.

I think the problem is I called every tab with `useState`. If I can create a function for calling them in one, problem can be solve.

How can I fix it?
Or if you can suggest me an alternative way it will be great.

```
export function LongTerm({ firminfo, longTerm }) {

  const [currentActiveTab, setCurrentActiveTab] = useState("1");

  const toggle = (tab) => {
    if (currentActiveTab !== tab) setCurrentActiveTab(tab);
  };

  const [currentActiveTab1, setCurrentActiveTab1] = useState("101");

  const toggle1 = (tab) => {
    if (currentActiveTab1 !== tab) setCurrentActiveTab1(tab);
  };

  const [currentActiveTab2, setCurrentActiveTab2] = useState("201");

  const toggle2 = (tab) => {
    if (currentActiveTab2 !== tab) setCurrentActiveTab2(tab);
  };
   
...
return
...
<Nav>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            className={classnames({
              active: currentActiveTab === "1",
            })}
            onClick={() => {
              toggle("1");
            }}
          >
            Karlılık
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            className={classnames({
              active: currentActiveTab === "2",
            })}
            onClick={() => {
              toggle("2");
            }}
          >
            Likidite
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>,
       ...
        
      </Nav>

<TabContent activeTab={currentActiveTab}>
        <TabPane tabId="1">
          <Row>
            <Col md="3">
              <Nav pills className="flex-column">
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink
                    className={classnames({
                      active: currentActiveTab1 === "101",
                    })}
                    onClick={() => {
                      toggle1("101");
                    }}
                  >
                    Brüt Kar Marjı
                  </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink
                    className={classnames({
                      active: currentActiveTab1 === "102",
                    })}
                    onClick={() => {
                      toggle1("102");
                    }}
                  >
                    FAVÖK Marjı
                  </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink
                    className={classnames({
                      active: currentActiveTab1 === "103",
                    })}
                    onClick={() => {
                      toggle1("103");
                    }}
                  >
                    Faaliyet Kar Marjı
                  </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                ...
              </Nav>
            </Col>
            <Col md="9">
              {/* ---------------------------------------------- */}

              <TabContent activeTab={currentActiveTab1}>
                <TabPane tabId="101">
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="12">
                      <OranChart firminfo={firminfo} type="Brüt Kar Marjı" />
                      <LongTermChart
                        firminfo={firminfo}
                        longTerm={longTerm}
                        a={3}
                        b={1}
                      />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane tabId="102">
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="12">
                      <OranChart firminfo={firminfo} type="FAVÖK Marjı" />
                      <LongTermChart
                        firminfo={firminfo}
                        longTerm={longTerm}
                        a={3}
                        b={2}
                      />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane tabId="103">
                  <Row>
                    <OranChart firminfo={firminfo} type="Faaliyet Kar Marjı" />
                    <Col md="12">
                      <LongTermChart
                        firminfo={firminfo}
                        longTerm={longTerm}
                        a={3}
                        b={3}
                      />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </TabPane>
                ...
                
              </TabContent>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </TabPane>
...}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-ddbvt

Comment: Can you please add a sandbox example?

Comment: @MathewsSunny https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-ddbvt
It is work fine. So, is the problem components?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try to use the [useCallback](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook in order to memorize your callbacks.

This would be an attempt to improve your performance, the callbacks functions are going to stay the same through the renders depends on the dependency list.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
```

Then for instance:

```
const toggle = useCallback((tab) => {
    if (currentActiveTab !== tab) setCurrentActiveTab(tab);
},[currentActiveTab]);
```

Like this your `toggle` functions will be defined at mount and only when `currentActiveTab` changes

Comment: I tried it but nothing's changed.